# German equivalent of “It works”

Tags: english-to-german, idiom, expression, idiomaticity

In English there is an idiom:

> It works.

Or more likely:

> That/It works for me.

I think that the following  is wrong, as *arbeiten* seems rather literal, but would it be a correct translation?

> Es arbeitet.

Comment: Welcome to German Language SE. I removed your second question, as there should indeed be only one question per question. It is a valid question though and you should ask it as a new question. However, you might want to clarify whether you are referring about the word *whore* when you are talking about English usuage (I doubt that the German word *Hure* is used in English).

Comment: *Hure* usually refers to someone who is literally a prostitute. It is quite derogatory in this context and simply an insult otherwise. *Luder* or *Schlampe* might be closer to what you are looking for, still derogatory and not something I would ever use but somewhat broader in meaning, a bit like the word “whore” in English.

Comment: "Arbeiten" means "to work" in the sense of "to have or perform a job or trade".

Comment: In this context, it's "Es *geht*" rather than "arbeitet".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you would like to express that something worked, like a suggested solution, you could say “Das hat funktioniert!” like “Hey, that worked!” so change “Es arbeitet” to “Es funktioniert”.

Comment: Thank you!~ :) This will help me sound way less illiterate, and will hopefully help me better learn those elusive words that hide behind more than one meaning. >:T (It added one to the list already.) I must apologize, for I moved the question about "hure" to another question altogether.

Comment: @HalkScout yeah I saw that, at the moment I posted my answer.  It is interesting to answer a question in language that is not my mother tongue, hopefully it was mostly correct. :)

Comment: Fixed it. For all those of who the dual question makes their eyes bleed, I shall not ask one doubled up in such a way again. Thanks again!

Comment: @HalkScout No problem at all :)  (and yeah the double question was not the best idea but otherwise you would have to ask two little questions, so it is ok :) )

Comment: @Feirell: There is nothing wrong with asking two little questions and it is actually the preferred way. Asking two related questions in one is never okay as it creates all sorts of trouble. I removed the second question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft ok ... then should I move my answer to ?

Comment: @Feirell: Depends what you mean by *move.* But yes, ideally you remove the appropriate part here and post it as an answer to the new question, once it is posted.

Answer (score 18):

The most commonly used expression would be

> Es funktioniert!

Sometimes it is phrased colloquially as

> Es geht!

or

> Es hat geklappt!

or

> Es läuft!

The latter is mostly used when you managed to get something running.

Comment: FWIW, "Es geht!" is the phrase I learned.  I studied German in the early '90s, and my teacher was a native speaker in his 70s, so there may be a generational difference in the choice of phrase.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede: "Es geht!" is very much in use nowadays, as well. There is no clear-cut distinction, but "Es geht!" is a bit more fitting in situations where "simple" things are described. A device, or a complicated plan can "funktionieren", but if you're simply asking "Can we meet on Sunday?", "Ja, das geht." would sound like a more suitable answer to me than "Ja, das funktioniert."

Answer (score 11):

As others have said

> <s>Es arbeitet</s>

does not sound right. Beyond that, “to work” can have many slightly different meanings and you need to distinguish them to find the proper German idiom.

> Es (hat) funktioniert!

would be the most generic translation, as explained in the other answers. It applies equally to a machine or to something you did but still does not sound as broad as the English phrase “it works”.

> Es läuft!

can be said of an engine or maybe some sort of machine or contraption but usually not of a procedure or manipulation.

> Es hat geklappt!

on the other hand applies to a manipulation (e.g. “How can you print this? I pressed on this button, it worked for me”) but not to a machine.

> Es geht

could also apply in some contexts but it seems more difficult to use correctly and can also express some skepticism (i.e. “it's barely OK”) so I would avoid it until you understand its nuances better.

> Es hat gereicht

(literally: *this is enough*) could also fit, especially in the negative form.

Finally, if you are talking about an appointment or some sort of agreement (“What about Sunday? That works for me!”) then you need something like

> Das passt (mir)

or, in a more reluctant tone,

> Das ist in Ordnung

and, again,

> Das geht

(see also O.R.Mapper's comment for another example with that one)

Comment: +1 for adding the "das passt"-translation which is missing in the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Im IT-Deutsch und unter Nerds ist auch

> Es funzt.

als Abkürzung für

> Es funktioniert.

gebräuchlich, wobei ein Maß an Unvollkommenheit und Hendsärmeligkeit zum Ausdruck gebracht wird.

Answer (score 3):

Ich als Deutscher würde sagen "es funktioniert" bzw. "Das/Es funktioniert bei mir".

Answer (score 1):

A native speaker would never say "Es arbeitet!". As an alternative to the already suggested *es funktioniert* you might also hear *es klappt* and *es tut*.

Answer (score 0):

Im Gegensatz zu anderen Antworten kann ich bestätigen, dass "Es arbeitet" durchaus in Gebrauch ist, aber nicht so universal wie die anderen, guten Beispiele, etwa "es funktioniert", "es läuft", "es geht" oder "es klappt".

```
Was macht das Entrauchungssystem des Berliner Flughafens? 
Es arbeitet wie erwartet.

Was macht der Motor?
Er arbeitet wieder.
```

Bei Anlagen und Maschinen ist das keine ungewöhnliche Formulierung, sondern gängig.

Bei abstrakten Dingen kann man es aber nicht verwenden:

```
Funktioniert meine Formel?
Sie funktioniert!
```

*Sie arbeitet* wäre hier falsch.

```
Probier mal einen roten Hut dazu! Wie kommt das? 
Es klappt! Es passt! Es geht.
```

Auch hier, wo es um das passive Erfüllen einer Funktion geht, erfüllt *es arbeitet* nicht die Bestimmung, it doesn't work.